# Why can I not use character ranges ('[a-z]') in SQL 'LIKE' queries on an ODBCConnection object in Excel 2010?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc, excel-2010

I have an Excel worksheet containing a list which is populated by using the list's ODBC connection in a macro, using this property:

```
ListObject.QueryTable.WorkbookConnection.ODBCConnection
```

It is configured to connect to its own workbook, because I have another worksheet containing a large amount of data:

```
ODBCConnection.Connection = "ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;" & _
    "DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "DriverId=1046;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;"
```

Then, to utilise this connection, a SQL query can be made, e.g.:

```
ODBCConnection.CommandText = _
"SELECT Column1 FROM [Worksheet2$] WHERE Column2 LIKE '%query%'"
```

The issue lies with the fact that these SQL queries do not match the SQL Server 2008 standard. In this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) it is stated that a LIKE expression may contain character ranges, e.g. `[a-z]` or `[^a-z]`. These do not operate as expected with the ODBC connection and are interpreted literally.

For example, the following query will return 0 records:

```
ODBCConnection.CommandText = _
"SELECT Column1 FROM [Worksheet2$] WHERE Column2 LIKE '%[^a-z]keyword[^a-z]%'"
```

If 'keyword' is a common keyword in Column1, this should return many records, as it searches for the keyword surrounded by non-letter characters.

Has anyone experienced this and found a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Update: I looked into using different command types on the ODBC object, but nothing useful (DAX commands or Excel formulae) are available until Excel 2013, which is unavailable to me...

Comment: Show the code which has a problem as well as the code which works.

Comment: @Ben Of course, done.

Comment: This is not SQL Server, this is the Excel ODBC Driver. The Excel ODBC Driver is not ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I cannot find any documentation regarding this particular limitation of the driver. Are there alternative drivers at all?

Comment: Excel is not really a database, and the Excel driver has only limited capabilities. If you need advanced features you should copy the data into a proper database and work with it there. (See my answer for suggestions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel ODBC Driver is a separate thing from SQL Server, and is not ANSI SQL compliant. It does not support this construct, and is ***not*** a fully-featured database engine. Instead it should bee seen as simply a convenience function to access Excel data, e.g. to import or export data. The same goes for the Text ISAM driver (CSV and Tab-separated files).

The Excel ODBC driver doesn't use exactly the same syntax and doesn't support the range `a-z` construct, you have to list all of the characters, so instead of `[^a-z]` you can use `"[!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"`

However the best workaround may be to simply use the Excel driver to copy data out of the Excel spreadsheet into another database, such as an MDB (Microsoft JET) or SCE (SQL Compact Edition) database, where you have more comprehensive features available to you.

Of course if you are working with fully-fledged SQL server, then the obvious solution is to copy the data into a staging table, then work with it there using the full capabilities of the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I had a play around with your query string and it turns out that the following works (I could obviously also use `LCASE` to halve the length of this): `[!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`. Unwieldy as it is, it will do nicely. If you update your answer I will accept it!

Comment: Also - unfortunately I have no choice about database platform, since this is part of an application which is being distributed as a standalone Excel workbook (I know... don't even get me started).